# no outputs from eventhub

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to read the data from eventhub
but the result it's only returning null values.

I converted a dataframe to json to send to the eventhub

```
dfSource_pandas = df.toPandas()
type(dfSource_pandas)
payload = dfSource_pandas.to_json(orient="records")
print(payload)
```

and this is the schema of the data

```
root
|-- alertId: string (nullable = true)
|-- score: double (nullable = true)
|-- severity: double (nullable = true)
```

I'm trying to read data from eventhub using

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```

from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DoubleType, StructType, StructField, 
StringType, LongType, BooleanType

```
schema = StructType([
StructField("alertId", StringType(), True),
StructField("score", DoubleType(), True),
StructField("severity", DoubleType(), True),
])


from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, to_json
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(**ehConf).load()
stream_data_body=
df.select(from_json(df.body.cast('string'),schema).\
alias('body')).select("body.*")
```

then the I'm getting null values with the correct schema like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you have a list of records in your payload, not individual records. In this case, you can try following schema instead:

```py
schema = StructType([
  StructField("alerts", ArrayType(
    StructType([
      StructField("alertId", StringType(), True),
      StructField("score", DoubleType(), True),
      StructField("severity", DoubleType(), True),
    ])))])
```

And then to get individual records, you need to [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) your payload - something like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, explode

stream_data = df.select(from_json(df.body.cast('string'),schema).alias('body')) \
  .select("body.*") \
  .select(explode("alerts").alias("alert")) \
  .select("alert.*")
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your answer! I tried the codes but it's not returning any values now,, can I ask you if I can use "alerts" when there is no "alerts" in the schema?

Comment: `alerts` -> field that was necessary to declare a field of array type. I believe that your main issue is with data layout - try to to `display(spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(**ehConf).load().select(col("body").cast('string'))` and see how data look like

Comment: Hi Alex thank you for your help! I think it was because I didn't declare alerts field like you said..could you help me with doing it? I tried to do it but not getting the right format.

Comment: have you used schema that I posted? Maybe you can post a sample of data that is displayed via `display` ?

Comment: yes not sure it's giving me some error for some reason.. so Im first trying to add the "alerts" filed to the json data that I posted. I first put the data in the dataframe in the column named alerts and coverted it back to json using to_json(). but I'm having backslashes inside the json. so it looks like this-->

Comment: [{"alerts":"[{\"alertId\":\"b137b337-c3e1-368e-829e-7ffc9e535k30\",\"score\":1.5708294809,\"severity\":0.9141861498},{\"alertId\":\"b137b337-c3e1-368e-829e-7ffc9e535k17\",\"score\":1.5708294809,\"severity\":0.9141861498},{\"alertId\":\"b137b337-c3e1-368e-829e-7ffc9e535k27\",\"score\":1.5708294809,\"severity\":0.9141861498},{\"alertId\":\"b137b337-c3e1-368e-829e-7ffc9e535k18\",\"score\":1.5708294809,\"severity\":0.9141861498},{\"alertId\":\"b137b337-c3e1-368e-829e-7ffc9e535k14\",\"score\":1.5708294809,\"severity\":0.9141861498}]

Comment: I'm not sure if Im doing this correctly,, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: aha - you have an array of objects that are arrays on their own... I'll try to look tomorrow

Comment: I really appreciate your help @Alex Ott!